# Scala for desktop

Tags: scala, frameworks, desktop

I know that there are exist established frameworks written in Scala for web development (Lift and Play).

I wonder if there are any frameworks for desktop development as well(even in early beta stage). What I'm after:
 - Application workflow
 - Custom ui components

Comment: Doesn't Scala let you use all of Java? So, Swing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scala comes with Java Swing wrapper, and you could also use SWT (just like you could use any other Java library in Scala). They are both suitable for desktop application development.

Answer (score 4):

JavaFx is comming, so try ScalaFx